# hibernate session factory scope

Tags: hibernate

What should be the scope of the Hibernate session factory in a web application? I am guessing HTTP session scope, is that correct?

Context: I have a spring web app that uses Hibernate. I have inherited years old code and the old developer has left long ago. The code seems to be using a global hibernate session factory for the application. This does not seem right to me, because this allows only one user to talk to the database at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be application scope.
Sessionfactory is like a connection pool, it generates Hibernate sessions for you.
It's an expensive created object and you shouldn't create it more than once during application lifetime.
Each request gets session from the session factory and does every DB operation through the session and not through the session factory.

Comment: In Spring talk that's Singleton scoped.